# C - Difficulties writing whole struct to Shared Memory

Tags: c, string, struct, shared-memory, dump

I'm having problems writing a structure to shared memory because when I do, the code only writes the first part of the structure.

Here's my data structure:

```
struct shmData{
    char number[4];
    char description[1020];
};
```

Here's my code:

```
//Structure Pointer - placed on SHM
struct shmstruct *ptr;
char description_to_write[1024] = {0};
struct shmData *data_ptr;
data_ptr = (struct shmData*) description_to_write;

//Shared Memory init
create_shm(&ptr);
printf("Started\n");

//Define Offsets
//init_shm(ptr);

//#########################

//Check if number exist
    if (!(strcmp("NO SUCH CODE\0", get_description(ptr, 6)))) {
        //-> If not, get next offset (nput) where to write new data
//      sem_wait(&ptr->mutex);
//      long offset = ptr->msgoff[ptr->nput];
//      printf("OFFSET: %li\n", offset);
//      if (++(ptr->nput) > NMESG)
//          ptr->nput = 0; /* circular buffer */
//      sem_post(&ptr->mutex);
//      printf("Buffer: %s", argv[2]);

    snprintf(data_ptr->number, 4, "%s", "6");
    snprintf(data_ptr->description, 1020, "%s\n", argv[2]);

    printf("DATA: %s\n", data_ptr->number);
    printf("DATA: %s\n", data_ptr->description);

    printf("description_to_write: %i\n", description_to_write);

    //strcpy(&ptr->msgdata[offset], );
    //sem_post(&ptr->nstored);
    //printf("Wrote...\n\n");
} else {
    //-> Else get offset of this number and put data to it
}
```

How should I write this? In the code above, I tried simply to display the description array but I only get the number back.

I need it to be written to shared memory as follows:

```
Number(space)(space)(space)Description
```

Shared Memory Dump looks like:

```
00003b0: 3120 2020 496e 7075 7420 4572 726f 720a  1   Input Error.
00003c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
*
00007b0: 3220 2020 4f75 7470 7574 2045 7272 6f72  2   Output Error
00007c0: 0a00 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00007d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
```

From debugger:

```
description_to_write[0] char    54 '6'  
description_to_write[1] char    0 '\000'    
description_to_write[2] char    0 '\000'    
description_to_write[3] char    0 '\000'
description_to_write[4] char    83 'S'  
description_to_write[5] char    111 'o' 
description_to_write[6] char    109 'm' 
description_to_write[7] char    101 'e' 
description_to_write[8] char    84 'T'  
description_to_write[9] char    101 'e' 
description_to_write[10]char    120 'x' 
description_to_write[11]char    116 't' 
description_to_write[12]char    10 '\n'
```

Ugly solution:

```
int i = 0;
        while(i < 4){
            if(data_ptr->number[i] == '\000'){
                data_ptr->number[i] = 32;
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: What output do you get *exactly*? Where does `data_ptr` come from?

Comment: sorry, i forgot some code, wait a minute

Comment: Also, are you sure you mean `argv[2]` and not `argv[1]`? If you are sure, do you make sure `argc` is greater than or equal to three?

Comment: and show what's inside `create_shm(&ptr);`

Comment: what is inside the function is not relevant, it works perfekt. I found the problem. in the first array the last char is always set to '\000' but I need it to be set to 32 -> space. its a problem of snprintf but how can i get it to work?

Comment: Way too much missing code.  Where is the initialization of data_ptr and the struct it points to?

Comment: Surely a small bit of code that pads a character array after the end of a null terminated string with spaces can be written?

Comment: `snprintf(data_ptr->number, 4, "%4d", 6);`

Comment: @Eddy_Em: `snprintf(data_ptr->number, 4, "%4d", 6);` will always write a null terminator at `data_ptr->number[3]` - and the `6` will never make it to the destination buffer.

Comment: @Michael Burr, oops. Really. Then `char number[4];` and `snprintf(data_ptr->number, 5, "%4d", 6);`

Comment: @Eddy_Em:  you shouldn't lie to `snprintf()` about the size of the destination buffer - it'll potentially write a '\0' after the last element of `number`, trashing whatever follows.

Comment: @Michael Burr, sorry: that was a misprint, should be: `char number[5];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 4 passsed to snprintf specifies the MAXIMUM number of chars to write. Not the amount to write. snprtinf retursn the number of chars it did write. So you are only printing 1 char, which leaves 3 nulls after it.

Just do:

```
snprintf(data->number,4,"%s    ","6");
```

That way it will try and print the string followed by 4 spaces, and print a max of 4 charcacters.

Comment: Almost - `data->number[3]` will be a null terminator instead of a space (or instead of a fourth digit for numbers larger than 999).

Answer (score 1):

Your ugly solution to use `snprintf()` and then rewrite '\0' characters as spaces has some flaws:

- `snprintf()` will never write a digit into `data_ptr->number[3]`. For strings longer than 3 characters it will truncate and write a '\0' instead of copying the 4th character in the source string.
- unless you're sure that the structure will be zero initialized before calling `snprintf()` then characters after the '\0' that `snprintf()` is required to write will not be set to anything by `snprintf()`.  That might not be a problem in your code as posted, but it's fragile in the face of changes to how the structure `data_ptr` points to is allocated and initialized.

Since the field is so small, you might consider something like:

```
memset( data_ptr->number, ' ', sizeof(data_ptr->number));
memcpy( data_ptr->number, "6", strlen("6"));
```

That still has a drawback that you need to add a bit more logic if the source string can possibly be longer than the field size. Also, if it's something that you'll be doing in more than one or two spots it can easily become a source of copy/paste bugs.

Here's a lightly tested function that you can use instead (though I'll admit that I hate the name):

```
size_t str2mem_padded( char* dest, size_t dest_size, char const* src, char fill)
{
    size_t result = 0;

    while (dest_size && *src) {
        *dest++ = *src++;
        ++result;
        --dest_size;
    }
    while (dest_size) {
        *dest++ = fill;
        --dest_size;
    }

    return result; // returns number of chars copied from src so you 
                   //   can determine if there was truncation
}
```

In your code, you might use the following instead of the call to `snprintf(data_ptr->number, 4, "%s", "6")`:

```
str2mem_padded( data_ptr->number, sizeof(data_ptr->number), "6", ' ');
```

Wow - that was a lot more effort than I thought it would be.